# AndEngine's GenericPool Handling 6 Sprites

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am using AndEngine to create a game.

I have randomly added sprites in my code that spawn just about every second.

I was informed that using a [Generic Pool](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/util/pool/GenericPool.java?r=2d9721dbefaf46f1b0bc67a869528c699a2a1f76) would save garbage collection in my case thats causing my game to lag at certain times.

So, here is what ive managed to come up with for my GenericPool..

```
public class FruitPool extends GenericPool<Sprite> {
private Sprite msprite;


public FruitPool(Sprite sprite) {
if (sprite == null) {
// Need to be able to create a Sprite so the Pool needs to have a TextureRegion
throw new IllegalArgumentException("The texture region must not be NULL");
}
msprite = sprite;
}

/**
* Called when a Bullet is required but there isn't one in the pool
*/
@Override
protected Sprite onAllocatePoolItem() {
return msprite;

}

/**
* Called when a Bullet is sent to the pool
 */
 @Override
protected void onHandleRecycleItem(final Sprite sprite) {
 msprite = sprite;
 msprite.setIgnoreUpdate(true);
 msprite.setVisible(false);
 }

 /**
 * Called just before a Bullet is returned to the caller, this is where you write your initialize code
 * i.e. set location, rotation, etc.
 */
 @Override
 protected void onHandleObtainItem(final Sprite fruit) {
 fruit.reset();
 }
 }
```

So as you guys see ive created a pool that i am able to add a Sprite to.

The problem is i have a method that randomly picks a number between 1 and 6. And i use a Switch statment to chose which sprite will be added the the scene.

How could i do this with the GenericPool? Having it hold six different sprites and being able to choose which one is added to the scene?

I was thinking maybe i could create a method that will add each Sprite to the Pool in my game, and then im stuck at the part where i find a way to select which sprite is selected out of the pool, such as providing a int that it takes to pick a sprite.

Thanks for the help in Advance guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, that is *not* how pools work.
In a pool, each call to `obtain` should obtain *another* un-recycled object. That means:

```
FruitPool pool = new FruitPool(...);
Sprite sprite1 = pool.obtain();
Sprite sprite2 = pool.obtain();
```

Now, `sprite1` and `sprite2` should *not* reference the same object. But with your implementation, they *do* and therefore it *won't* work when you will obtain and use 2 items simultaneously.

You should implement it like this:

```
public class FruitPool extends GenericPool<Sprite> {
// ===========================================================
// Constants          
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================          
// Fields         
// =========================================================== 
private final TextureRegion mTextureRegion;
// ===========================================================          
// Constructors          
// =========================================================== 
public FruitPool(final TextureRegion pFruitTextureRegion) {
    this.mTextureRegion = pFruitTextureRegion;
}
// ===========================================================          
// Getter & Setter          
// =========================================================== 

// ===========================================================          
// Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces          
// ===========================================================  
@Override
protected Sprite onAllocatePoolItem() {
    return new Sprite(0, 0, this.mTextureRegion);
}
@Override
protected void onHandleObtainItem(final Sprite pItem) {
    pItem.reset();
}
@Override
protected void onHandleRecycleItem(final Sprite pItem) {
    pItem.setVisible(false);
    pItem.setIgnoreUpdate(true);
}
// ===========================================================          
// Methods          
// ===========================================================  

// ===========================================================          
// Inner and Anonymous Classes          
// ===========================================================  
}
```

This way, multiple sprites can be requested from the pool at the same time, and the pool will actually fill it's purpose.

About your question, a pool is implemented using a *stack*, so you can not take out a specific item of it - only the one at the top. I recommend you then to create 6 different fruit pools, each one for another fruit type.

You should either extend `Sprite` and include a field `type`, for the type of the current fruit, so you'd know to which fruit pool you should send it when you are done, or use the `setUserData` and `getUserData` methods to save information about the type of the current fruit.

Comment: Wow, Thanks alot Jong! I understand it much better now! SO basically i supply the Texture region to the pool and i can use poolItem.obtainItem() for example to obtain my first fruit. Ill just need to create 6 different pools for each one. Now how does it work if one of them goes off the screen? How does the recycling work? And use the same sprite again?

Comment: When you are done with a sprite (It goes off the screen, for example) you call it's pool method `recyclePoolItem`. Now, the pool keeps that sprite and the next time you call `obtainPoolItem`, it will return it rather than allocating a new one (And that's the purpose of a pool)

Comment: Thanks alot Jong. Youve helped alot! Thanks!!

Comment: So ive ran into an issue. I add sprites multiple times. So if the pool item hasnt been recycled yet and i call on it to obtain another sprite. What happens? Does it create as many as needed?

Comment: Yes. If the pool has no recycled items to give, it will allocate a new one (call `onAllocatePoolItem()`).